# How to use upstash redis in langchain Customized Conversational Retrieval Chain

Tags: next.js, redis, artificial-intelligence, langchain, vercel-ai

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { Message as VercelChatMessage, StreamingTextResponse } from "ai";

import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

import { ChatOpenAI } from "langchain/chat_models/openai";
import { PromptTemplate } from "langchain/prompts";
import { SupabaseVectorStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/supabase";
import { Document } from "langchain/document";
import {
  RunnableSequence,
  RunnablePassthrough,
} from "langchain/schema/runnable";
import {
  BytesOutputParser,
  StringOutputParser,
} from "langchain/schema/output_parser";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";

export const runtime = "edge";

type ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput = {
  question: string;
  chat_history: VercelChatMessage[];
};

const combineDocumentsFn = (docs: Document[], separator = "\n\n") => {
  const serializedDocs = docs.map((doc) => doc.pageContent);
  return serializedDocs.join(separator);
};

const formatVercelMessages = (chatHistory: VercelChatMessage[]) => {
  const formattedDialogueTurns = chatHistory.map((message) => {
    if (message.role === "user") {
      return `Human: ${message.content}`;
    } else if (message.role === "assistant") {
      return `Assistant: ${message.content}`;
    } else {
      return `${message.role}: ${message.content}`;
    }
  });
  return formattedDialogueTurns.join("\n");
};

const CONDENSE_QUESTION_TEMPLATE = `Given the following conversation and a follow up question, rephrase the follow up question to be a standalone question, in its original language.

Chat History:
{chat_history}
Follow Up Input: {question}
Standalone question:`;
const condenseQuestionPrompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(
  CONDENSE_QUESTION_TEMPLATE,
);

const ANSWER_TEMPLATE = `You are an energetic talking puppy named Dana, and must answer all questions like a happy, talking dog would.
Use lots of puns!

Answer the question based only on the following context:
{context}

Question: {question}
`;
const answerPrompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(ANSWER_TEMPLATE);

/**
 * This handler initializes and calls a retrieval chain. It composes the chain using
 * LangChain Expression Language. See the docs for more information:
 *
 * https://js.langchain.com/docs/guides/expression_language/cookbook#conversational-retrieval-chain
 */
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const messages = body.messages ?? [];
    const previousMessages = messages.slice(0, -1);
    const currentMessageContent = messages[messages.length - 1].content;

    const model = new ChatOpenAI({
      modelName: "gpt-4",
    });

    const client = createClient(
      process.env.SUPABASE_URL!,
      process.env.SUPABASE_PRIVATE_KEY!,
    );
    const vectorstore = new SupabaseVectorStore(new OpenAIEmbeddings(), {
      client,
      tableName: "documents",
      queryName: "match_documents",
    });

    const retriever = vectorstore.asRetriever();

    /**
     * We use LangChain Expression Language to compose two chains.
     * To learn more, see the guide here:
     *
     * https://js.langchain.com/docs/guides/expression_language/cookbook
     */
    const standaloneQuestionChain = RunnableSequence.from([
      {
        question: (input: ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput) =>
          input.question,
        chat_history: (input: ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput) =>
          formatVercelMessages(input.chat_history),
      },
      condenseQuestionPrompt,
      model,
      new StringOutputParser(),
    ]);

    const answerChain = RunnableSequence.from([
      {
        context: retriever.pipe(combineDocumentsFn),
        question: new RunnablePassthrough(),
      },
      answerPrompt,
      model,
      new BytesOutputParser(),
    ]);

    const conversationalRetrievalQAChain =
      standaloneQuestionChain.pipe(answerChain);

    const stream = await conversationalRetrievalQAChain.stream({
      question: currentMessageContent,
      chat_history: previousMessages,
    });

    return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
  } catch (e: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: e.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

I'd like to use upstash redis in above code.

https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain-nextjs-template/blob/main/app/api/chat/retrieval/route.ts

Redis use like below code.( this code is used kv but i want use upstash instead.

https://github.com/vercel-labs/ai-chatbot/blob/main/app/api/chat/route.ts

```
import { kv } from '@vercel/kv'
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse } from 'ai'
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai-edge'

import { auth } from '@/auth'
import { nanoid } from '@/lib/utils'

export const runtime = 'edge'

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
})

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const json = await req.json()
  const { messages, previewToken } = json
  const userId = (await auth())?.user.id

  if (!userId) {
    return new Response('Unauthorized', {
      status: 401
    })
  }

  if (previewToken) {
    configuration.apiKey = previewToken
  }

  const res = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages,
    temperature: 0.7,
    stream: true
  })

  const stream = OpenAIStream(res, {
    async onCompletion(completion) {
      const title = json.messages[0].content.substring(0, 100)
      const id = json.id ?? nanoid()
      const createdAt = Date.now()
      const path = `/chat/${id}`
      const payload = {
        id,
        title,
        userId,
        createdAt,
        path,
        messages: [
          ...messages,
          {
            content: completion,
            role: 'assistant'
          }
        ]
      }
      await kv.hmset(`chat:${id}`, payload)
      await kv.zadd(`user:chat:${userId}`, {
        score: createdAt,
        member: `chat:${id}`
      })
    }
  })

  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream)
}
```

https://upstash.com/blog/langchain-redis

example code is here. but I wanna use code in custom chain.

```
import { type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { LangChainStream, StreamingTextResponse } from "ai";

export const runtime = "edge";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
const { messages } = await req.json();
const { stream, handlers } = LangChainStream();

    const latestMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];
    
    return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);

}
```